# Python inheritance weirdness depending on how the subclass is called

Tags: python

I am getting an error when I call a subclass from another class, but not when I call it directly. It seems that when I create an instance of this subclass from a different class the information in the superclass is not getting passed to the subclass.

```
class HBatom(object):
    def __init__(self, struct, sele, **kwargs):
        self.struct = struct
        self.sele = sele

class HDonor(HBatom):
    def __init__(self,struct,sele,**kwargs):
        super(HDonor,self).__init__(struct,sele,**kwargs)
        self.find_H()
    def find_H(self):
        bonded = self.struct.select(''.join(["bonded to ", self.sele.getSelstr()]))
```

This works

```
import HBonds
HB = HBonds.HDonor(structure,Nsel,f_wat=1)
```

But when I create an instance of a class that contains a dictionary of HDonors and then tell it to populate I get an error

```
HN = HBonds.HNtwrk(structure,1)
HN.build_HNtwrk()

AttributeError: 'HDonor' object has no attribute 'sele'
```

Executing with pdb shows me that in the second case *self* contains no attributes of the HBatom parent class. How is it possible for *self* to contain that info in the first case but not in the second?

Sorry, I didn't include HNtwrk in the original post. The total code is almost 400 lines, so I don't want to include more than necessary. Here are the relevant parts of HNtwrk

```
class HNtwrk:
  def __init__(self,structure, f_wat = 0):
    self.f_wat = f_wat
    self.struct = structure
    self.rh_o = 2.5
    self.rn_o = 3.5
    self.Dons = dict()
    self.Accs = dict()

def build_HNtwrk(self):
    Dsele = self.struct.select(DonStr)
    Asele = self.struct.select(AccStr)
    self.addDons(Dsele)
    self.addAccs(Asele)

def addDons(self, Dsele):
    for pairs in iterNeighbors(Dsele,self.rn_o,Asele):
        iN = pairs[0].getIndices()[0]
        iA = pairs[1].getIndices()[0]

        if iN not in self.Dons:
            Hdon = HDonor(self.struct,pairs[0].getSelstr,f_wat=self.f_wat)
            self.Dons[iN] = Hdon
```

The code trips when I set Hdon because HDonor.find_H() requires HBatom attributes. It is as if HBatom.__init__() is not called during the HDonor init when an HDonor instance is created from HNtwrk. Just to be clear, HNtwrk appears in the same file as the other classes.

Comment: Are you sure that code is *completely* accurate, e.g. no MI?

Comment: At the very least, you have a HBatom/HBatoms typo (and are missing a `class ` at the start)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: What's an MI? I only know this as the abbreviation for myocardial infarction (sorry, comes with the job), and I do hope it means something else here.

Comment: @Tim: [Multiple Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) (which can sometimes lead to...)

Comment: You haven't shown the `HNtwrk` code, either. Surely it's important too?

Comment: I have corrected the HBatom typo. That was just a mistake when typing into stackoverflow. I have also included parts of HNtwrk. Thank you for looking this over.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **concrete superclass name**, that is `HBatom`, instead of `super`.

When you call `super(HDonor, self)`, and `self` is actually a child of `HDonor`, `super`'s result will pass function calls to `HDonor` class, not the `HBatom` as you expected.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5066411/13767) for more details on why `super` creates problems.

Comment: You make a good point about using super, however changing to HBatom.__init__(self,struct,sele,**kwargs) had no effect in this case

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the code for `HNtwrk` or `build_HNtwrk`, but I'll guess that `HNtwrk.__init__` doesn't invoke the parent's `__init__` method.

Comment: It sounds like HNtwrk doesn't inherit HBatom, but rather initializes an `HBonds` object. I agree it should be shown though.

Comment: I've now included the relevant (I hope) parts of HNtwrk. HNtwrk does not invoke the HBatom \__init__ because it is not meant to be a subclass of HBatom. Instead it is meant to contain dictionaries of HBatoms and track the relationships between them.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Turns out it wasn't an inheritance issue at all.
I was getting the problem because I called

```
Hdon = HDonor(self.struct,pairs[0].getSelstr,f_wat=self.f_wat)
```

instead of which should have been called with

```
Hdon = HDonor(self.struct,pairs[0].getSelstr(),f_wat=self.f_wat)
```

Thus I wasn't passing what I thought I was passing and this triggered a poorly written exception that I had included in HBatom.__init__() (which I failed to include as a code snippet). Thanks to those who offered suggestions. In the future I will create a separate small code that will isolate the problem and post the full code.