# super() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python

```
class car(object):
    """A simple attempt to represent a car."""
    def __init__(self,make,model,year):
        self.make=make
        self.model=model
        self.year=year
    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """getting full name of the car"""
        longname=str(self.year)+" "+self.make+" "+self.model
        return longname

class battery():
    """defining the new battery class"""
    def __init__(self,battery_size=70):
        self.battery_size=battery_size
    def describe_battery(self):
        """Print a statement describing the battery size."""
        print("This car has a " + str(self.battery_size) + "-kWh battery.")
    def get_range(self):
        if self.battery_size==70:
            range=210
        elif self.battery_size==90:
            range=270
        message = "This car can go approximately " + str(range)
        message += " miles on a full charge."
        print(message)

class ElectricCar(car):
    def __init__(self,make,model,year):
        super(object,ElectricCar).__init__(model,make,year)
        self.battery=Battery

my_tesla=ElectricCar('tesla','benz','2016')
print my_tesla.get_descriptive_name
my_tesla.battery.describe_battery()
my_tesla.battery.get_range()
```

Above code throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 27, in <module>
  File "python", line 25, in __init__
TypeError: super() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Above code throws the error showing the above one which I have posted. As it is throwing the `super()` argument error. How to solve this error. In which the 25th line is:

```
super(object,ElectricCar).__init__(model,make,year)
```

and 27th line is

```
my_tesla=ElectricCar('tesla','benz','2016')
```

Comment: `class battery` should inherit from `object` too (and while you are at it change it to `Battery`). Also, `super`'s first argument should be the class itself (not an instance) and the second one `self`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066315/why-is-super-broken-in-python-2-x

Comment: Is this Python 3 or Python 2?

Comment: @poke Python2 judging by `print`

Comment: @DeepSpace Ah yeah, down there, missed that one.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing mistake at the time of calling super().
super() takes two parameter, first one should be the type and another one should be the instance .

So your code

```
class ElectricCar(car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        super(object, ElectricCar).__init__(model, make, year)
        self.battery = Battery
```

should be

```
class ElectricCar(car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery = Battery
```

Please note that **__init__()** parameters order is different also.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in the order of the arguments of the `super` call. But there are others problems on your code that I have fixed below:

```
#code throws super argument error
class Car(object): # Class name should be upper case
    """A simple attempt to represent a car."""
    def __init__(self,make,model,year):
        self.make=make
        self.model=model
        self.year=year
    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """getting full name of the car"""
        longname=str(self.year)+" "+self.make+" "+self.model
        return longname

class Battery(object): # Upper case
    """defining the new battery class"""

    def __init__(self, battery_size=70):
        self.battery_size=battery_size

    def describe_battery(self):
        """Print a statement describing the battery size."""
        print("This car has a " + str(self.battery_size) + "-kWh battery.")

    def get_range(self):
        if self.battery_size==70:
           range=210
        elif self.battery_size==90:
           range=270
        message = "This car can go approximately " + str(range)
        message += " miles on a full charge."
        print(message)   

class ElectricCar(Car):

    def __init__(self,make,model,year):
        super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(make,model,year) # Fix super call and init order of params
        self.battery=Battery() # Upper case and missing ()


my_tesla=ElectricCar('tesla','benz','2016')
print my_tesla.get_descriptive_name
my_tesla.battery.describe_battery()
my_tesla.battery.get_range()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `super()` incorrectly. The first argument should be the *current type*, and the second argument the *current instance*. So it should be like this:

```
super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(model, make, year)
```

Note that `object` does not belong into any parameter here.

Once you have fixed that, you will get a new error which is that `Battery` does not exist. In order to fix that you need to change it to `battery` and you will also want to call it to actually create a new `battery` object:

```
class ElectricCar(car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(model, make, year)
        self.battery = battery()
```