# Python Child object not accessing parent attribute

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt5, multiple-inheritance

so I'm writing a program in PyQt5 and making use of the QObject class. Here's the basic program.

```
class Object(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Object, self).__init__(parent)
        self.field = []


class Object2(Object):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Object, self).__init__()
        self.field.append(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = Object2()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Object2' object has no attribute 'field'
```

I can't seem to find the cause of problem. Is it that a python child class cannot access it's parents attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is because of the arguments you are passing into `super`. In Python 2 it takes 2 arguments: The first argument is the current class (`Object2`), and the second argument is the current instance (`self`).

*The issue is you've passed the **parent** class instead of the **current** class.*

So you want:

```
class Object2(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Object2, self).__init__() # Current class: Object2
        self.field.append(1)
```

In Python 3, it is no longer required to pass these arguments into `super`. So you would just do:

```
class Object2(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.field.append(1)
```

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5066411/7220776

Python 2 docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super

Python 3 docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super